# Erro no posicionamento do menu ( visualizado no celular ) utilizando o Bootstrap

Tags: menu

Estou desenvolvendo um site http://www.hobbyanimal.com.br/ esta tudo correto quando se trada da exibição pelo PC. Quando estou visualizando pelo celular o menu não aparece da mesma forma que aparece no PC. Ele fica tudo junto em uma "caixa". Esta caixa esta posicionada a esquerda, quando se consegue adivinhar que o menu esta ali e clica os sublinks abrem por trás da logo.

Isso já aconteceu com alguém?

Obrigado!

Comment: perceba que  o erro esta no posicionamento de sua Logo e não no menu, pelo que vi ele funciona corretamente. Coloque seu código de forma que consigamos testar e lhe ajudar melhor, vi no seu site que esta faltando a imagem "images/partners/partner_bg.png" também...trate as propriedades da Logo, como a position ou algo assim e poste o código ai se não der certo.

Comment: Seria bom você trazer mais conteúdo para sua pergunta, pois, uma vez que você consertar sua página não será mais possível entender que erro acontecia e sua pergunta não terá mais utilidade para ninguém, a não ser para você mesmo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu site esta assim:

```
<div class="navbar-header" style="position:absolute; z-index:2;">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img    src="images/logo.png" alt="logo"></a>
                </div>
```

Troque o `position: absolute` por `position: relative` Ele se ajustara de acordo com o Layout, da forma que esta você obriga a imagem ficar ali independente do que aconteça com a pagina.

Ficara assim:

```
<div class="navbar-header" style="position:relative; z-index:2;">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo"></a>
                </div>
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado!

Comment: Existe alguma forma de exibir o menu de uma forma diferente?

Comment: @ViniciusGonçalves se a resposta resolver o problema iniciar então marque ela como resposta, assim a questão sera fechada. quanto ao menu, leia a documentação que você vera que da para customizar quase tudo no bootstrap, apenas manipulando as classes nav-bar http://getbootstrap.com/components/